# Finding the smallest root of $a(1-a)^{n-1} = s$

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, systems-of-equations, roots, radicals

Let $n >2$ be an integer, and let $0<s \le \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$ be real.

Is there a way to find explicitly the unique solution $0<a<\frac{1}{n}$ to the equation $a(1-a)^{n-1} = s$?

This is the **smallest** root of the polynomial $p(a)=a(1-a)^{n-1}$.

The condition $s \le \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$ comes from the fact that $$\max_{a \in (0,1)}a(1-a)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{n}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n-1},$$

so if $s > \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$ there is no solution in $(0,1)$. Moreover, since the function $f(a)=a(1-a)^{n-1}$ is increasing in $(0,\frac{1}{n}]$, we see that if $0=f(0)<s<f(\frac{1}{n})= \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$ then there exist a **unique** solution $a \in (0,\frac{1}{n}]$ as mentioned above.

*Comment:* This question is related to [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278523/finding-the-closest-matrix-to-textso-n-with-a-given-determinant).

Of course, there is no general formula for the roots of polynomials of order 5 and higher, but this is a very specific polynomial, and I am asking only for the smallest root.

If an explicit formula is out of reach, what estimates can be done? Is there a known method for estimating the smallest root of a polynomial?

**I am interested in estimates from above and from below.**

**Edit:** It seems any formula will be extremely messy, [even for $n=3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve++x(1-x)%5E2%3Ds).

Comment: There is a very likely scenario such that there is no root in the given range.

Comment: When $n\to\infty$?

Comment: The conditions seem strange.  First, $s<a$ always, and for large $n$ it should really be $s\lt\lt a$.  Yet these facts are not included in the problem setup.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon I elaborated on the technical conditions. (Didn't want to scare people away:).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I elaborated on the technical conditions. (Didn't want to scare people away:).

Comment: What are you trying to say >.> Scaring me is a good thing.

Comment: Updated and improved

Comment: try putting all roots in the min function

Answer (score 2):

I think that we have a good approximation using the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant built around $a=0$

$$f_n(a)=a(1-a)^{n-1}\sim \frac {6 a-2  (n+1)a^2 } { 6+4  (n-2)a+ (n-2) (n-1)a^2}=g_n(a)$$

whose error is $$\frac{ (n-1) n (n+1) (n+2)}{72} a^5 \sim \frac {(an)^5}{72n}$$

If we consider the weighted norm
$$\Phi_n=n^2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1-n} \int_0^{\frac 1n} \Big(f_n(a)-g_n(a)\Big)^2\,da$$ its maximum value is $9.23\times 10^{-7}$ for $n=4$.

The factor $n^2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1-n}$ is the reciprocal of the area of the enclosing rectangle of the plot for the area of interest.

So, it seems that we can have a "decent" approximate solution at the price of a quadratic equation.

Using
$$s=k\,\,\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$$

- Trying for $n=5$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.008476 &  0.008476 \\
 0.2 & 0.017589 &  0.017589 \\
 0.3 & 0.027473 &  0.027473 \\
 0.4 & 0.038310 &  0.038310 \\
 0.5 & 0.050368 &  0.050366 \\
 0.6 & 0.064060 &  0.064052 \\
 0.7 & 0.080097 &  0.080070 \\
 0.8 & 0.099896 &  0.099797 \\
 0.9 & 0.127298 &  0.126841 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

- Trying for $n=15$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.0026330 &  0.0026330 \\
 0.2 & 0.0054812 &  0.0054812 \\
 0.3 & 0.0085902 &  0.0085901 \\
 0.4 & 0.0120237 &  0.0120235 \\
 0.5 & 0.0158746 &  0.0158739 \\
 0.6 & 0.0202881 &  0.0202852 \\
 0.7 & 0.0255133 &  0.0255033 \\
 0.8 & 0.0320515 &  0.0320149 \\
 0.9 & 0.0412728 &  0.0410995 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Using instead the $[3,3]$ Padé approximant of $f_n(a)$, the improvement is quite spectacular.

- the error becomes $\sim \frac {(an)^7}{7200n}$
- the considered norm has a maximum value is $4.01\times 10^{-11}$ for $n=7$.

Repeating the same calculations as above

- Trying for $n=5$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 &  0.008476 &  0.008476 \\
 0.2 &  0.017589 &  0.017589 \\
 0.3 &  0.027473 &  0.027473 \\
 0.4 &  0.038310 &  0.038310 \\
 0.5 &  0.050366 &  0.050366 \\
 0.6 &  0.064052 &  0.064052 \\
 0.7 &  0.080070 &  0.080070 \\
 0.8 &  0.099797 &  0.099797 \\
 0.9 &  0.126839 &  0.126841 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

- Trying for $n=15$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 &  0.0026330 &  0.0026330 \\
 0.2 &  0.0054812 &  0.0054812 \\
 0.3 &  0.0085901 &  0.0085901 \\
 0.4 &  0.0120235 &  0.0120235 \\
 0.5 &  0.0158739 &  0.0158739 \\
 0.6 &  0.0202852 &  0.0202852 \\
 0.7 &  0.0255033 &  0.0255033 \\
 0.8 &  0.0320148 &  0.0320149 \\
 0.9 &  0.0410989 &  0.0410995 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting approach. I have some questions: How can the error term be $\frac{ (n-1) n (n+1) (n+2)}{72} a^5 \sim \frac {(an)^5}{72n}$, doesn't it supposed to include a term like $a^n$ or something like that in $f_n-g_n$ ? . Also, I am curious for where does the factor term $n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1-n}$ come from in the expression for $\Phi_n$. Does it arise naturally somehow? in what way?

Comment: Fot the first question : yes, it is $f_n-g_n$ by Taylor. For the second one, it is $\frac  s n$ which is the area of the rectangle (just to have some "normalization"). Very interestin problem for sure. If you are ready for cubic equations, the result is very good.