# Is this quadratic polynomial monotone at solutions of this cubic?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, optimization, symmetry, cubics

Let $0<s < \frac{4}{27}$. The equation $x(1-x)^{2}=s$ [admits exactly two solutions in $(0,1)$:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604922/how-many-roots-of-x1-x2-s-are-there-in-0-1) Denote by $a,b$ be these solutions, and suppose that $a<b$.

Does
$$
(1-a)^2+2a^2<(1-b)^2+2b^2
$$
hold?

The limitation on the range of $s$ is due to $$\max_{a \in (0,1)}a(1-a)^{2}=\frac{4}{27},$$
which is attained at $a=\frac{1}{3}$.

I checked this numerically. I hope for an analytic argument which does not require solving explicitly the cubic.

---

*Here is some partial information:*

Define $F(x)= (1-x)^2+2x^2$. Then
$$
F'(x)=2(3x-1)>0 \iff x > \frac{1}{3}.
$$
Thus $F|_{(0,\frac{1}{3})}$ is decreasing, while $F|_{(\frac{1}{3},1)}$ is increasing.

Unfortunately, this does not seem to help.

---

The motivation for this problem come from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599605/how-to-minimize-x-12y-12z-12-under-the-constraint-xyz-s).

Comment: There aren't any real roots which satisfy the given conditions, so the inequality is trivially true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given inequality
$$(1-a)^2 + 2a^2 < (1-b)^2 + 2b^2$$
is equivalent to
$$0 < (b-a)\cdot(3(b+a) - 2)$$
i.e.
$$ b+a > \frac{2}{3}.$$
If $c$ is the third root of the equation $x(1-x)^2 = s$, then Vieta's formula says $a+b+c = 2$, so the inequality is equivalent to
$$ c < \frac{4}{3}.$$
But if $c \ge \frac{4}{3}$, then
$$c(c-1)^2 \ge \frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}-1\right)^2 = \frac{4}{27} > s,$$
so no value of $c\ge \frac{4}{3}$ is a root of $x(x-1)^2 = s$.

Therefore the given inequality is true.

Comment: Much simpler than mine and (+1). Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks, that is a perfect answer! This is exactly the kind of argument that I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Using my answer to your previous question, we have (after trigonometric simplifications)
$$a=\frac{4}{3} \cos ^2\left(\frac{1}{6} \left(\cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{27 s}{2}-1\right)+2 \pi \right)\right)$$
$$b=\frac{4}{3} \sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{6} \left(\cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{27 s}{2}-1\right)+\pi \right)\right)$$
Then
$$(1-a)^2+2a^2=\frac{1}{3} \left(5-4 \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{27 s}{2}\right)\right)+2 \cos
   \left(\frac{2}{3} \cos ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{27
   s}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$
and
$$(1-b)^2+2b^2=\frac{1}{3} \left(5+4 \sin \left(\frac{1}{3} \sin
   ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{27 s}{2}\right)\right)-2 \cos
   \left(\frac{2}{3} \sin ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{27
   s}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$ So, if
$$\Delta=\Big[(1-b)^2+2b^2\Big]-\Big[(1-a)^2+2a^2\Big]$$
$$\Delta=\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}\sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{6} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{27
   s}{2}-1\right)\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{27 s}{2}-1\right)\right) $$

$\Delta$ has the same sign as $\sin \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{27 s}{2}-1\right)\right) $ which varies between $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $0$.

So $$\color{red}{\Delta ~\geq~  0 \quad \forall s \in \left(0,\frac 4{27}\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a proof for why $a<b$? ($\cos^2(...) < \sin^2(...)$ in your answer)? I am trying to figure out the details myself but thought maybe you will have a simpler explanation. (BTW, I didn't downvoted your answer).

Comment: OK, I think I solved it.